# Mask object that extends java.util.Date from returning true with instanceof

Tags: java

I have a class that extends from java.util.Date. However I need to make sure that the condition `instanceof Date` returns `false`. Is this possible? The reason is because I need to override the functionality of a framework I am integrating with that will change the behavior of my object if it is of type Date.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

public abstract class KronosDateTime extends Date implements Serializable {

    public KronosDateTime(final long time) {
        super(time);
    }

    public KronosDateTime() {
        super();
    }

    public abstract double toDoubleValue();

}


public final class KronosDateTimeImpl extends KronosDateTime {
    public KronosDateTimeImpl() {
        this(System.currentTimeMillis(),true);
    }
}

public final class Kronos {
    public static KronosDateTime call(PageContext pc) {
        KronosDateTimeImpl dateTime = new KronosDateTimeImpl(pc);
        System.out.println(dateTime instanceof java.util.Date); // Should return false
        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not using `extends`. By definition, an instance of a class which extends another class is an instance of both classes.

But you can use composition instead:

```
class KhronosDateTime /* doesn't extend Date */ {
  private final Date date;

  KhronosDateTime(long time) {
    this.date = new Date(time);
  }

  // Whatever methods using date.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible (given the current code).

By saying `A extends B` you are saying *any instance of A is also an instance of B*.

Therefore that `instanceof` check will always return true. Of course, *your* code can avoid that check, and do what Eran suggests for example. But nothing would prevent *other* people from using instanceof.

Therefore the real answer here is: learn what inheritance means. You can't have the cake but still eat it. Either your date class extends Date, or it does **not**.